# Excel cell content into multiple rows into another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a requirement in excel where i want to copy each text that ends with pulistop into a row of another sheet. ex:

Setting up the configuration.

Creating environment.

Pushing the tasks.

Now assume that above text is in one cell and i want to copy each sentence that ends with pulistop into individual rows of a new sheet. like below.

---

Setting up the configuration.

---

Creating environment.

---

Pushing the tasks.

---

Please help me in doing this as i have many no. of sheets which needs this modification.

Thanks in advance.
Chakri.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can be useful for you:

1. Copy the cell(s) into clipboard (Ctrl+C).
2. Paste into Notepad or similar text editor. *Note: in Notepad the lines will appear next to each other, but nevermind, the line jumps are still there.*
3. Replace in text editor all " (double quotes) with nothing.
4. Copy the whole text of the editor.
5. Paste into Excel.

This works in my case. If you have many cells like this next to each other, with this method you can process all at once with the same effort. Will this work for you?